# the object file of the executable is unchanged when i change the main.cpp file (cmake)

Tags: cmake, debian

In Debian I run the following code in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(projectname)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(proj source/main.cpp)
```

This was configured and built in the `~/projectname` directory with

`cmake -S . -B build` and
`cmake --build build`

The `proj.dir` directory is in `~/projectname/build/CMakeFiles/proj.dir`, and `main.cpp` is in `~/projectname/source`.

Running `./build/proj` works fine, but changing the `main.cpp` after running the first instance (no matter when I've made the `main.cpp` file, before or after building the executable) does not affect the object file of `main.cpp` in `build/CMakeFiles/proj.dir/source`, so running `./proj/main.cpp` again leads to the original instance being executed. No amount of overwrites of `main.cpp` are affecting the object file. the version of cmake im running is 3.25.1.

I thought that I've messed up somewhere by misplacing the `main.cpp` file in a different directory, it is not the case. The `main.cpp` file that I'm overwriting is in the source directory. neither does deleting the entire projectname directory and starting over the build process with cmake help, as it leads to the same error

Comment: Please share a [mre] of your files and the commands you call to build them.

Comment: hello, i ran it with cmake -S . -B build in the ~/projectname directory, and the cmakelists.txt file has pretty much nothing, its just cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20), project(projectname), set(cmake_cxx_standard 20) and add_executable(proj source/main.cpp). the proj.dir directory is in ~/projectname/build/CMakeFiles/proj.dir, and main.cpp is in ~/projectname/source.]

Comment: Thanks. Please [edit] that into your question. Readability is much better there, questions should stand on their own and comments are just to ask for clarifications.

Comment: sorry, ive made a mistake writing the question. what im running instead is ./build/proj

Comment: I'm not seeing the actual command you use to compile. The cmake -S . -B build call simply configures the build files for the project. What command do you execute to actually build the executable? Does reconfiguring (repeating the cmake configuration and then executing the build command again) help?

Comment: i either run ./proj ../somefile.cpp (which executes the original instance of the main.cpp object file) or ./proj/main.cpp to execute the main.cpp file

Comment: "which executes the original instance of the main.cpp object file" - One cannot **execute** the **object** file. "... to execute the main.cpp file" - The **source** file cannot be executed either. You explanations are very confusing.

Comment: The command `cmake -S . -B build` just **configures** the project. But configuration doesn't create an executable. How do you **build** the project, so executable is created?

Comment: i apologize for the ambiguity and the errors, as im not familiar with cmake at all. the executable was created with cmake --build build. the error is that once the main.cpp file is altered, the alteration is not reflected upon executing the executable, as it still runs the first instance of main.cpp.

Comment: After editing `main.cpp` you need to run `cmake --build build` again; that way the executable will be rebuilt in accordance to the content of the source file.